# Intuition on $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+1}{k} = \binom{n + 2}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Intuition on  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k+1}{k} = \binom{n + 2}{n}$

I'm trying to understand what both sides count and why this equality holds. 
If the right hand side counts the number of binary strings of length $n+2$ with n zeros, how does the left hand side partition those binary strings?

Would thinking about the right hand side in terms of a binary string and trying to relate the left hand side to it be less intuitive by thinking about the equality in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the $(k+2)$th position is $1$ and the positions after it is $0$. Then $\binom{k+1}{k}$ counts the number of binary strings (of length $n+2$ with $n$ zeros) under these condition.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Is $(k+2)$ arbitrary?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the reasoning. Why does having a 1 at the $(k+2)$ position imply that $\binom{k+1}{k}$ counts the number of binary strings?

Comment: Notice that the summation is taken over $k=0,\ldots, n,$ and the $1$ in the $(k+2)$ position can be considered as the rightmost position of $1$

Comment: For example, if $n=3$, then $\binom{1}{0}$ counts $11000$; $\binom{2}{1}$ counts $10100$ and $01100$; $\binom{3}{2}$ counts $10010$, $01010$, and $00110$; $\binom{4}{3}$ counts $10001$, $01001$, $00101$, and $00011$

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this problem in this way :
Suppose we have n+2 numbers consist of two 1 and n zeroes,at first we
Can fix one of 1 position let's say in the n+2'th position then we must find the ways of creating the string with lenght of n+1 numbers that have one 1 and n zeroes the way to doing this is $n+1 \choose n$,then u can find the second way of creating these strings by replacing the 1 that we put at n+2 position with 0 and take that 1 one place back and fix that in n+1's position abd like previous level,we have n positions left that contains n-1 zeroe and one 1 and the ways of creating these strings is $n \choose n-1$ and so on... at last u can get this sum $\sum_{i=1}^n {i+1 \choose i}$ which is your left side of equation and as you know it's equal to $n+2 \choose n$ which is right side.